# Tuple Serialize in ApiController - C#

Tags: c#, serialization, tuples

I'm using ApiController and I want it to return a list of tuples, like: List<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>>.
(My action returns it in IHttpActionResult object.)

The problem is, when I receive the response and I try to deserialize it to the above object - list of tuples, I got a strange result the json in my client side is: [{"**m_Item1**":"2020-01-30T12:13:23","**m_Item2**":"2020-01-30T12:13:23"}].

I want it to look like this: [{"**Item1**":"2020-01-30T12:13:23","**Item2**":"2020-01-30T12:13:23"}].

Maybe somebody knows how can I avoid it?

I know that I can create an object which contains 2 fields of datetimes, but I don't want because my client does not know the server, so it also doesn't know the object that I declare...
Or maybe you have another idea to resolve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The client does not know that you are using a tuple. That doesn't stop you from using it, does it? Then why you stopped from using a DTO instead of a tuple? The client doesn't care what's on the server. It is enough for the client to know the structure of the json that it receives.

Comment: As a last resort, if you don't want to create a separate model, use an anonymous class.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to create a model in both sides server and client, but to use anonymous class it's also not so comfortable, so if I have no way to serialize tuple I will create a seperate model... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, it's extremely easy to avoid this issue. Create a proper dto class like every good person should and return it from your api instead.

Comment: Thank you, but what about the issue of the client doesn't know my dto class? I thought that it's better to use a generic type. Not?

Comment: So, just inform the client about the way your response looks like. It is way easier to parse a proper dto than a generic class.

Comment: Sorry about the re-asking... but I mean that I don't want to create an object in both server and client. Is it a standard way? I wanted to use type of microsoft so I used a tuple. Maybe you know a way to serialize tuple correctly? Thank you again!

Comment: A standart way is to create a separate project called MyProjectName.DTO (provided u already have MyProjectName.Client and MyProjectName.Server). Move all the DTO types into that separate project and reference it from both client and server.

Comment: Thank you about explanation! Currently I prefare not to create a common project for this because it's single action... but if I don't get answer to my first question (about the serialization) , I think I will not have a choice... anyway - thanks and have a good day!